# Как добавить проверку русского языка в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, проверка-орфографии

Как сделать проверку орфографии в **IDE PhpStorm**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Скачиваем [словарь](https://www.winedt.org/dict/Russian.zip).
- Создать директорию, в которую положим распакованные словари. Например, я, в ОС linux семейства создаю директорию тут: `~/.phpshtorm/dic`.
- Переходим в настройки(`Editor`->`Spelling`) и добавляем словари:

[image: Настройки]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Перезагружаем **IDE PhpStorm**

Answer (score 0):

для PhpStorm 2022:

Ctrl + Shift + S -> Editor -> Natural Languages -> "+" -> Русский